# Replace a string in CentOS filenames

Tags: linux, centos

I have a CentOS server (version 6.6) , This server contains many folders and files but all the files have a string in their names .
For example : The-first-show-(www.mysitename.com).mkv 
I have changed my website address to www.mynewsite.com and I want to replace my new address in all the files . How can I do so ? Please remember that all the files are in different locations . I need something that works on the whole server . thanks

Answer (score 1):

We're not a script writing service so some pointers ...

You could use [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) to locate all of the files that contain the string `www.example.com` and then use it's `-exec` function to run the [rename](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rename) command to erm rename the files. Note that different distros ship with different rename commands but the one I lined to is good for CentOS.

Comment: Can I get the command that does so? I'm not a professional in linux and server stuff

Comment: You don't need to be a professional to click and read the links that were given to you.  If you need further help than that you should either go to a site for Linux beginners (this is not that place, this site is specifically for professionals in linux and server stuff) or hire a professional.

Comment: @yoonix: I just read your profile and agree wholeheartedly.

Comment: From my short experience on SF, this profile description is spot on I must say ...